# Convert a text document/string to dataframe in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, text-mining, text-parsing

I have extracted this text from a PDF using Apache tika. I want to split this text in such a way that I get a single row per question/answer. End result needs to be a tabular structure. 
Here's the text that I am working on (Mock up to avoid violations):

```
\n\nDoes your plan offer a travelers insurance \nand all (Part D) benefits?\n\nYes\n\nSelect the type of your stay: Enhanced Alternative\n\nDescribe the components of your travelers plan\n(select all that apply):\n\n: Standard Cost-Sharing\n: Out-of-bond James\n: Standard Cost-management\n: Long Term membership \n\nSponsor attests that it will comply with 42 CFR \n423.154.\n\n: Sponsor attests that it will comply with 42 \nCFR 423.154.\n\n'
```

I have tried splitting on "\n\n" "?" and ":" but it does not generalize well.

- | Does your plan offer a travelers insurance and all(Part D) benefits? |       Yes
- | Select the type of your stay:| Enhanced Alternative
- | Describe the components of your travelers plan (select all that apply):|  Standard Cost-Sharing, Out-of-bond James, Standard Cost-management, Long Term membership
- | Sponsor attests that it will comply with 42 CFR 423.154: | Sponsor attests that it will comply with 42 CFR 423.154:

A vertical pipe represents a column.